# How do I create a new menu in Android to undertake a certain action without opening up another preference window?

Tags: android, menu, preference

If you click a button on the menu it opens up an XML preference window, but I just want the button to call another method that creates a record in my sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call this method in onCreateOptionsMenu() and do not inflate menu.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    createRecord();
    return false;
}
```